# Custom font not working?

Tags: 2013

I installed a custom font using [this guide](http://www.evokeit.com/adding-custom-fonts-sharepoint-2013/). The font for the theme that I chose to change (the default wood theme) has changed, but it is not the font that I uploaded to the site.

New Wood theme font:

[image]

What my font looks like:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the path for the font file (file.spfont) from te compose look?

Comment: (MySharePointSite)/_catalogs/theme/15/fontscheme001.spfont

Comment: If you put this put directly on the browser is it downloading the file?

Comment: Yes it downloads the file if I enter the full path.

Comment: And what about the actual fonts uploaded in the layout/fonts directory can you download this through browser? If this is also correct  then recheck the spfont file.

Comment: I can't download the .svg file. Is that intended or is that a problem? It just takes me to a blank page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60417/discussion-between-s-merchant-and-mdomin45).